# Class auto generated from XSD return all the same values from array?

Tags: c#, object, xsd

I cant understand why the below is happening. 
See the code and output example. 
Why are the 3 array elements outputting the same value when they are clearly being set to different values.

Jim 
Frank 
James

James 
James 
James

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        users allUsers = new users();
        allUsers.user = new usersUser[3];
        usersUser userConfig = new usersUser();

        userConfig.username = "Jim";
        allUsers.user[0] = userConfig;
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[0].username);

        userConfig.username = "Frank";
        allUsers.user[1] = userConfig;
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[1].username);

        userConfig.username = "James";
        allUsers.user[2] = userConfig;
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[2].username);

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[0].username);
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[1].username);
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[2].username);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


using System.Xml.Serialization;


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class users {

    private usersUser[] userField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("user")]
    public usersUser[] user {
    get {
        return this.userField;
    }
    set {
        this.userField = value;
    }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class usersUser {

    private string usernameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string username {
    get {
        return this.usernameField;
    }
    set {
        this.usernameField = value;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are changing the same object over and over before assigning it, hence you are changing it even for the ones that are already assigned, the last name you set it to is the one that sticks. You have to do it like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        users allUsers = new users();
        allUsers.user = new usersUser[3];
        usersUser userConfig = new usersUser();

        userConfig.username = "Jim";
        allUsers.user[0] = userConfig;
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[0].username);

        userConfig = new usersUser();
        userConfig.username = "Frank";
        allUsers.user[1] = userConfig;
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[1].username);

        userConfig = new usersUser();
        userConfig.username = "James";
        allUsers.user[2] = userConfig;
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[2].username);

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[0].username);
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[1].username);
        Console.WriteLine(allUsers.user[2].username);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Create new objects for each index in the array, instead of using the same three times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 usersUser userConfig = new usersUser();
```

you only declare this once. Then, you just overwrite the `userConfig.username`field everytime with another value. try it like this:

```
usersUser userConfig = new usersUser(); // <-- new instance
userConfig.username = "Jim";
allUsers.user[0] = userConfig;


usersUser userConfig1 = new usersUser(); // <-- another new instance
userConfig1.username = "Jim";
allUsers.user[0] = userConfig1;
```

Comment: So allUsers.user[0] = userConfig; is pointing to userConfig rather than setting allUsers to the values stored in userConfig?

Comment: allUsers.user[0] = userConfig is going to point to whatever value you assigned to it *last*. As i said, you need to make a new usersUser() for every username you want to assign.

Comment: Bingo thanks. I was just misunderstanding how it was pointing to the values.